# Understanding boundary class concept

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I can't understand this concept clearly.

> For a class $\mathfrak{H}$ of groups,
>    define $b( \mathfrak{H}):= (G \in  \mathfrak{C} \ \setminus \mathfrak{H}: G/N \in \mathfrak{H}$ for all $ 1 \neq N \trianglelefteq  G ) $. 
>   Obviously, $b(\phi)= b( \mathfrak{C})= \phi$.
>       We say that a class of groups  $\mathfrak{B}$ is a boundary if  $\mathfrak{B}=b( \mathfrak{H})$ for some classes of groups $ \mathfrak{H}$.

Well, I remember my teacher said that, for example, $S_{3}$ is in the boundary of nilpotent class since it is non-nilpotent group but every subgroup in $S_{3}$ is nilpotent. 
But I can't actually relate between what my teacher said and the definition above!
If this idea is correct, how? If not, can you help me with correcting my misunderstanding and suggest a reference to use? Thank in advance.

(Note: I am only studying finite groups.)

Comment: I guess, he meant that every proper *quotient* of $S_3$ is nilpotent.